# Too much wine used in coq au vin

Tags: chicken, wine, marinade

The NYT coq au vin recipe called for 3 1/2 cups red wine and marinate overnight, then reduce to make the sauce.  Husband added an extra 2-3 cups of wine to the marinade. It is now the morning after. Which should I do? Reserve 2 cups only of the marinade to reduce (as probably 1 cup has been absorbed by the chicken?), or take the time simmering all of the wine down.

Answer (score 6):

[Marinades are generally surface treatments](https://amazingribs.com/tested-recipes/marinades-and-brinerades/science-of-marinades-and-brinerades), especially in thicker cuts.  With the exception of salt (if any in the marinade), I doubt your chicken has absorbed any marinade. So, your issue is the higher quantity of liquid, and flavoring of the wine.  I think you could go either way...remove some, or reduce.  If it were me (so as not to be wasteful), I would just cook as normal, reduce longer, and taste and re-season along the way.

Comment: When I cook with wine I usually use a whole bottle (no use to keep it as it would not be drunk and it would not last long enough for the next time I need wine) and I never had problems with too much wine. You are likely to end up with more sauce.